# iOS Objective-C required reading

Tags: objective-c

I have an iOS app in the app store. I'm working on some new features for it. Some code i've hand crafted, other bits of pieced together from answers on this wonderful site, however I feel like my code is a bit ugly, and could be improved. When I see something below this, I don't full understand how it is used automatically, and how it implies a loop exactly. So i'm wondering what would be some good reading material to learn more about objective-c before maybe working on my app more.

I've been surfing some articles on the ios dev center website, but if you guys can suggest some specifics to look at, i'd be grateful. I do have an understanding of heap & stack memory management from when I did C++, but I have to admit im not as solid on how objective-c does it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }
```

Comment: I've tried to answer your general question below; but as for the specific example you cite... I'm not sure what you mean about `commitEditingStyle` implying a loop. In that method you're asked to perform the editing operation (typically a delete) that the user requested, which may or may not require a loop depending on how your data is structured. There are some other table view delegate/datasource methods that sort of have an implicit loop -- e.g. the table view loops through its visible cells to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development and Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a thorough general understanding of iOS & ObjC, I'd suggest a book or two:

- [iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321821521) by Conway & Hillegass
- [Beginning iOS 5 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430236051) by Mark, Nuttig, & LaMarche

And/or following the [Stanford iOS course](http://itunes.apple.com/us/course/ipad-iphone-app-development/id495052415) on iTunes U. There are a few good blogs for tutorials & explanations out there, too: [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) and [Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://cimgf.com) are the first to come to mind.

For something more specific to table views or other subsystems, the [Programming Guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) in Apple's developer documentation aren't bad.

Comment: 2nd the Standford course + Ray's site. Apple's WWDC videos are also good though not so much beginner level.

Comment: @skinnyTOD Ray is pretty good about hand holding for beginners.